# zsh/mercurial help on every command

Tags: terminal, mercurial, zsh

Every command I make in terminal while in zsh I get the mercurial help appended.
Example:

```
$ ls
Applications   Developer      Library        Pictures       VirtualBox VMs
Consensus      Documents      Movies         Projects
Desktop        Downloads      Music          Public

haaduken at nachi in ~Mercurial Distributed SCM

basic commands:

 add           add the specified files on the next commit
 annotate      show changeset information by line for each file
 clone         make a copy of an existing repository
 commit        commit the specified files or all outstanding changes
 diff          diff repository (or selected files)
 export        dump the header and diffs for one or more changesets
 forget        forget the specified files on the next commit
 init          create a new repository in the given directory
 log           show revision history of entire repository or files
 merge         merge working directory with another revision
 pull          pull changes from the specified source
 push          push changes to the specified destination
 remove        remove the specified files on the next commit
 serve         start stand-alone webserver
 status        show changed files in the working directory
 summary       summarize working directory state
 update        update working directory (or switch revisions)

use "hg help" for the full list of commands or "hg -v" for details
$
```

I have absolutely no idea why. Any ideas how I can stop this? A lot of people are saying alias, but hg isn't in my alias list at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you add a Mercurial command to your PS1 variable? Some people do this, to display the current branch or bookmark.
What does 'echo $PS1' show?

It's possible you added an incorrect Mercurial command there, which results in printing the help message.

Comment: `$ echo $PS1
%{$fg[magenta]%}%n%{$reset_color%} at %{$fg[yellow]%}$(box_name)%{$reset_color%} in %{$fg_bold[green]%}${PWD/#$HOME/~}%{$reset_color%}$(hg_prompt_info)$(git_prompt_info)
$(virtualenv_info)%(?,,%{${fg_bold[white]}%}[%?]%{$reset_color%} )$`

hg_prompt_info looks promising.

Comment: Most likely, hg_prompt_info is a function in your .zshrc or another dotfile. If you can find it, that's probably what's causing the issue.

Comment: Well, after almost a year I finally figured out the problem. It was the theme I was using. It had that hg_prompt_info in it.. thanks @mathiasdm

Comment: Wow, glad to be able to have helped after a year :-) Pretty impressive to see this after that time.